# What's "|" mean in C# programming?

Tags: c#

I frequently read code like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue | System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default)
```

in C# program,sometimes parameter like this,what's this meanning ?

I have searched from google,but has no valuable answer,the '|' can not property parsing in Google engine,maybe i use the wrong way when searching.

Comment: when | is used as || it is OR operator and here it used as Enum values

Comment: see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kxszd0kx.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it seems that it is a [Flags enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx)

```
[Flags]
public enum Types
{
    None = 0,
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
    Type3 = 4,
}
```

So

```
Types someType = Types.Type1 | Types.Type2;
```

Would mean that it has both types.

Answer (score 4):

'|' is the bitwise `or` operator, in this case it is used to create an enum value with all the given bits set.

`DebuggingModes` is a bitflag enumeration - this means each bit can indicate a flag and a single `DebuggingModes` value can be used to signal multiple flags.

Enums can be made bitflags using the `BitFlagsAttribute`:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum DebuggingModes
{
   Default = 0,
   DisableOptimizations = 1,
   EnableEditAndContinue = 2,
   ...
}
```

Comment: It depends. If you're comparing Booleans, it's a non-short-circuiting OR comparison (`||` is short-circuiting).

For integral types (which includes enums), it's indeed the bitwise OR.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bitwise OR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) iin C#. Here it is used to create an [enum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) with all the given set of bits.

> Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, | computes the bitwise OR of its operands. For bool
>   operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the
>   result is false if and only if both its operands are false.

Answer (score 1):

It is a logical `or` operator. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) for a complete explanation.

**Main explanation in the doc:**

Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, | computes the bitwise OR of its operands. For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the result is false if and only if both its operands are false.

Answer (score 0):

when | is used as || it is OR operator and here it used as Enum values